# Adding an attribute to element

Tags: jquery, attributes, element

I'm trying to add an attribute to an element. The attribute would indicate a certain height and the position of the center of the screen width. That's why I tried using jquery in order to get the position of the center of the screen width.

So, this code:
`<script>$("p.slider-price").attr('data-position', '145, ' + (($("p.slider-price").parent().width() - $("p.slider-price").outerWidth()) / 2));</script>` correctly adds the attribute `data-position: "145, 500"`.

However I tried using the same code for another element: `$("p.house-description").attr('data-position', '200, ' + (($("p.house-description").parent().width() - $("p.house-description").outerWidth()) / 2));`, but for some reason the calculus always returns 0, so it just adds `data-position: "200, 0"`.

The final code is:

```
<script>
$("p.slider-price").attr('data-position', '145, ' + (($("p.slider-price").parent().width() - $("p.slider-price").outerWidth()) / 2));
$("p.house-description").attr('data-position', '200, ' + (($("p.house-description").parent().width() - $("p.house-description").outerWidth()) / 2));
</script>
```

So the problem is that the calculus from the second line doesn't work properly(always returns 0), while the one from the first line works flawlessly. What's the problem?

Edit: Here's the HTML code:

```
p class="slider-price" data-in="fade" data-step="1" data-delay="250" data-out="fade">
                        $50,000
                    </p>    
                    <p class="house-description" data-in="fade" data-step="1" data-delay="350" data-out="fade">
                        Modern Apartment in Kiev, Ukraine
                    </p>
```

Basically this part of code: `(($("p.house-description").parent().width() - $("p.house-description").outerWidth()) / 2)` always returns 0; Don't know why.

Comment: can you show us the html code?

Comment: So basically it's not about setting an attribute at all, but elements not returning the expected width ?

Comment: Basically this part of code: `(($("p.house-description").parent().width() - $("p.house-description").outerWidth()) / 2)` always returns 0; Don't know why.

Comment: what is hte parent of this block of html code?

Comment: It's a div of 100% window width and 630 px height. Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uc0sunLb/

Comment: if you did not add any margin to your <p>, or padding to your parent at all. <p> usually take the width of parent. therefore containerWidth == childOutWidth

Comment: well why does the first <p> have a correctly set attribute then?

Comment: Are you sure it sets correctly? when i throw your code into codepen, the first line doesn't set either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just to follow up my post in comment section. Your p.slider-price is by default display:block. It takes the inner width of the parent.

You need to set the width of your p.slider-price/description for your js code to have effect

```
p.slider-price{
  width:400px;
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  console.log( $("p.slider-price").parent().width() );
  console.log( $("p.slider-price").outerWidth() );
  var leftDist = (parseInt($("p.slider-price").parent().width()) - parseInt($("p.slider-price").outerWidth()))/2;
  console.log( leftDist );                       
  $("p.slider-price").attr('data-position', '145, ' + leftDist);

});
```

codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNRORQ